# Python Function Behavior

Tags: python

If I have a function that builds up a **min-heap** structure using list of tuples of the form:
**[(vertex),length,(another_vertex),...........]**, I wrote that function to take two inputs **the heap structure** and the new element called **triplet** of the previous form. It supposed to construct the heap from the added triplets without duplicates according to the **"(vertex)"** and in ascending manner according to **"length"**, and I wrote it as follows:

```
def heap_add_or_replace(heap, triplet):
   heap.append(triplet)
   # Sorting according to the first element of every triplet to have duplicates get next to each other
   vertexSort = sorted(heap, key = lambda x: x[0])
   # Sorting according to the distance in ascending manner
   lenSort = sorted(vertexSort, key = lambda x: x[1])
   # Function to remove duplicates
   def remvDuplicate(struct):
     check = set()
     result = []
     for i in struct:
        if i[0] not in check:
            result.append(i)
            check.add(i[0])
     return result
  # Setting the final return value
  heap = remvDuplicate(lenSort)

return heap
```

My question is what is the difference between calling the functions with the following two methods:

```
triplet_heap = list()

a = heap_add_or_replace(triplet_heap,((2,3),0.9,(1,0)))
print("the new heap is: " + str(a))

b = heap_add_or_replace(triplet_heap,((7,2),0.3,(2,2)))
print("the new heap is: " + str(b))
```

and,

```
new_heap = list()

heap_add_or_replace(new_heap,((2,3),0.9,(1,0)))
print("the new heap is: " + str(new_heap))

heap_add_or_replace(new_heap,((7,2),0.3,(2,2)))
print("the new heap is: " + str(new_heap))
```

because in the second method the function doesn't behave correctly:

**Correct output - First call:**

the new heap is: [((2, 3), 0.9, (1, 0))]

the new heap is: [((7, 2), **0.3**, (2, 2)), ((2, 3), **0.9**, (1, 0))]

**Wrong output - Second call:**

the new heap is: [((2, 3), 0.9, (1, 0))]

the new heap is: [((2, 3), **0.9**, (1, 0)), ((7, 2), **0.3**, (2, 2))]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does it do instead? Also, have you seen the `heapq` module?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  If we look at just the first call: `a = heap_add_or_replace(triplet_heap,((2,3),0.9,(1,0)))
`, are you asking why, after this call, `a` and `triplet_heap` are different?

Comment: You guys the first method outputs the triplets sorted in ascending manner according to the second term of each "the length", but in the second method which is my course auto-grader it does not and I don't know why!

Comment: So does the "second method", because it's the same method.  The difference is just that you're using the return value from that method in the first case but you aren't in the second. So what?

Comment: Have a look at the outputs and notice the order of 0.3 and 0.9

Comment: Right.  That's what's expected, as my answer explains.  The original list is never sorted.  The list returned by the function IS sorted.  That's the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, the "correct case", you're looking at the return values from the `heap_add_or_replace` function.

In the second case, the "incorrect case", you're looking at what happens to the original `list` each time you pass it into the `heap_add_or_replace` function.

In the `heap_add_or_replace` function, you copy the input `list` the first time you do a sort.  The result of that sort, and everything that's done after that isn't reflected in the original list.  So the original list you passed in doesn't ever get sorted or filtered for duplicates.  That's why the two cases are different.

Comment: I do re-assign the value of the heap at the end and return it, if that's what you're aiming for.

Comment: Yes.  The assignment at the end of your function doesn't affect the list you passed in.  It just changes the variable `heap` that is local to the function so that it points to a different list. Only the first line of the function affects the list you pass into it.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused because I do return the final version of the heap. Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: Yes...just use the value you return from the function.  That's the difference between the first and second case.  In the second case, you're not using the function's return value at all.

Comment: Here's another way to say it.  To fix the second case, just put `new_heap =` in front of each of the two calls to the function, and you'll get the results you want.

Comment: I totally understand that, this isn't my problem. The second method as I mentioned is my course hard code grader and I can't change it. That's the big idea, and I think my implementation is fine.

Comment: Ok.  I still don't quite understand your issue maybe.  If you understand what I've been saying, then I expect you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an analogous to both of your cases:

```
a = []

def f(l):
    l.append(0) #affect global variable a
    l = 5       #new local variable created inside the function
    return l    #return l = 5!

#first case
b = f(a)        #b is assigned value from return l (5)

#second case
print(a)        #printing global variable not result from function ([0])
```